# Install sass direct react js without webpack.config

Tags: reactjs, sass

I tried to install below mentioned details for install sass on react js but not working

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Thanks,

Comment: hi @kuriakose-j-a, could you add some detail about what is the error message that you get?

Comment: Please provide more details. How did you try to install and what kind of error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

In the long term, you would want to configure your Webpack and use it to preprocess your saas files. If you can please share your Webpack config and the error message maybe some one can help.

Right now you can use a tool like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/), which will watch and spit out CSS files. Now you can use this css file in your project without making any changes to the webpack config.

I generally use it for light html/css websites.